# What are the numbers / symbols to the right of my reputation counter?

Tags: support, reputation, design, symbols

I'm referring to the colored circles with numbers next to them on the top of the page, to the right of my reputation counter. What do they represent?

Comment: There must be an earlier Meta Stack Overflow post about this - it is one of the things that are not at all obvious to new users.

Answer (score 3):

I just accidentally hovered over them, and found out that they are my badge counters. Never mind!

Comment: For what it's worth, you can get extra information about pretty much anything on any Stack Exchange page by hovering over it.