# What is the meaning of the two numbers below my name?

Tags: support, user-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the numbers / symbols to the right of my reputation counter?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68692/what-are-the-numbers-symbols-to-the-right-of-my-reputation-counter)

What is the meaning of the two numbers separated by a dot below my name?

Comment: Reputation, gold badges, silver badges, bronze badges

Comment: Pretty much everywhere on SE sites, if you have this type of doubt, just let your mouse hover over it. There's tooltips everywhere.

Comment: On a side note, don't let JSLint scare you if you're trying to adhere to commonly-accepted JavaScript best-practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) count, you have one silver badge and seven bronze badges on Stack Overflow at the moment.