# What do the numbers to the right of my name (point score) mean?

Tags: support

I don't pay much attention to them but what do the numbers to the right of my name / point score mean (like 2 / 13 / 41 below)? I know this should be super obvious but I just don't know.

[image]

Comment: So got that many badges and you had no idea? :P:P

Comment: If you can hover, hovering your mouse is often your friend on Stack Exchange.

Comment: thx, tried hovering, in chrome, it takes a few seconds - I guess I'm impatient ;-)

Comment: yet it probably takes a minute or two to type this post...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the numbers and symbols to the right of my reputation counter?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68692)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are the number of gold, silver and bronze [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) you've earned.

See also [What are badges?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges)